# how to print to screen a vector?

Tags: class, iterator

I'm implementing the show Deal Or No Deal, there's a class 'box' which in the main file i used to store the random values of the boxes and than, i saved each box in the vector. im trying now to print in the screen the boxes saved in the vector whit the iterator,without succeeding, any help???

```
//random assignation of pound value to the 22 boxes
for (int e = 1; e < 23; e++)
{
    int pos;
    bool op = true;
    while (op)
    {
        pos = rand();
        if (pos > 0 && pos < 23)
        {               
            if (myArray[pos][1] == 0)
            {
                myArray[pos][1] = 1;
                op = false;
            }
        }
    }
    box b(e, myArray[pos][0]);  //creating the class box
    game_box.push_back(b);  //function of the vector to insert a data in it
}

//show boxes
for (auto a = game_box.begin(); a!= game_box.end(); a++)
{
     cout << *a << endl;
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail? I can see at least two possibilities. 1) Your vector stores boxes not pointers to boxes, so you don't need to dereference it. Remove the `*` from `cout << *a << endl`. 2) Does your box class have an `operator<<` declared?

Comment: i compiled with the '*a' and it says "error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'box' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" 
the vector is suppose to store the class box yeah. 
yeah, i think that the operator << has been declared here

#include "Source1.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

because in the rest of the code it works...

Comment: however i tried without the * sign and it just give me the exact same error :/

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the dereference operator (`*`) from the a.

Next you need to add an output operator for box. Assuming that box is a class with member data `member1` and `member2` this would look something like:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const box& b)
{
  out << box.memeber1 << " " << box.member2;
}
```

The key point is that you need to define this operator for *every* class.

Once you've done that and got it working you might also like to look at [this library](http://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/) which defines `<<` operators for all stl containers. This lets you replace

```
for (auto a = game_box.begin(); a!= game_box.end(); a++)
{
     cout << *a << endl;
}
```

by simply

```
cout << game_box << endl;
```

Comment: my data members are public, would i need to use friend function anyway?

Comment: You don't need to, but you should probably do it anyway in case you need to make them private later.

Comment: it unfortunately did not work.. it is just printing out random negative numbers

Comment: That's probably what is in the boxes. I suspect there are other bugs in your code, in particular: do you initialise all the entries of your arrays?

Comment: no, and that was my problem. I manage to find the solution using pointers tho.

Answer (score 0):

this works..

```
class Box 
{
float pound_contained;
int box_number;

public:

Box(int box_number, float pound_contained);
int getbox_number();
float getpound_contained();
};
int Box::getbox_number()
{
return this->box_number;
}
float Box::getpound_contained() 
{
return this->pound_contained;
}

main()
{
vector<Box> game_box;
Box* boxes = &game_box[i];
cout <<boxes->getbox_number()<<endl;
}
```